# Does SQLAlchemy support RLIKE in mysql?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Trying to find a way to implement `RLIKE` in a sqlalchemy query connected to mysql database.

Our hostnames are terribly complex, so, using `LIKE` is not an option for us.  I have dozens of SQL queries that successfully use `RLIKE` to query groups of hosts that have various packages installed on them, but not sure how/if sqlalchemy supports it.

My Pure SQL  where clauses look like this:

```
(device RLIKE '^ab-.*-ceaa-b[0-9]{2}$' and package = 'package-rpm')
OR
(device RLIKE '^ab-.*-cezz-b[0-9]{2}$' and package = 'other-package-rpm')
```

I am a beginner in python and am making some progress, but am at the point where I need to implement `RLIKE` or something similar into my script:

```
conditions = []
conditions.append(and_(Package.device.like('ab-pp-%'), Package.package == 'package-rpm'))
conditions.append(and_(Package.device.like('ab-zz-%'), Package.package == 'package-rpm'))

Package.query.filter(or_(*conditions)).all()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use SQLAlchemy with any function you want, by using [`op`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.ColumnProperty.Comparator.op) method:

```
conditions.append(and_(Package.device.op('rlike')('^ab-.*-ceaa-b[0-9]{2}$')), Package.package == 'package-rpm'))
```